# OSX bundle icons into the executable

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, clang

I want to make a single-executable unbundled app as opposed to an app bundle. I can embed the `Info.plist` file into the exe with `-sectcreate __TEXT __info_plist` linker option. Can I embed the icons too?

Comment: Ever find a solution, or is this basically impossible?

Comment: @tmm1 nop, made an app folder and all...

Comment: I found some really old NeXT references to `-sectcreate __ICON app` but I don't think that works anymore.